# How to have POST ActionHandler return the GET ActionHandler by a custom Attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

Our system is MVC2 authenticated by ADFS 2. So when a user clicks on a bookmark for `http://www.foo.com/Car/Details/3`, this hits our `Car` controller and calls our `Details` GET action handler and passes 3 in as the ID (all basic MVC stuff). So we have this ActionHandler decorated with a `[Authorize]` attribute and have ADFS2 hooked up, so the page then redirects to our auth server which then redirects back to our app, but with a POST (all basic ADFS stuff). The problem is that this redirect is a POST and therefore our `Details` POST handler is called, but clearly it doesn't have the data I need.

Now I have identified some code that detects this scenario and this code looks something like this:

```
[Authorize]
[MySpecialHttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(long id)
{
    var model = GetModel(id);
    return View(model);
}

[Authorize]
[MySpecialHttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(long id, ViewModel model)
{
    /***START OF SPECIAL CODE***/
    // If we were posted to by ADFS, redirect to the GET handler.
    if (Request.Form["wa"] != null && Request.Form["wa"].ToLower().Contains("signin"))
    {
        // We were posted to here but need to respond with the GET view.
        return Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    /***END OF SPECIAL CODE***/

    var result = Something.SaveData(model);
    return result.ActionResultToReturnWith;
}
```

The problem with this is that I need to do this on **every single POST** ActionHandler in the app and I really don't want to do that. Given that I already have custom attributes on all of these ActionHandlers, I would like to use those attributes to inject this functionality for me.

Now the `MySpecialHttpGet` and `MySpecialHttpPost` are nothing incredibly special that you really need to know about other than they extend `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. I would LIKE to add code in the `MySpecialPost` attribute to inject that functionality.

So my question:

**How would I add code to perform this kind of check in this Attribute?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, we have not found the solution we wanted and are simply pasting that code (well, a function call with that code in it) at the beginning of EVERY controller.